# Django - How to delete an article?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a button on the framework django that let me delete my own article on my blog. I tried to create a code for this functionality, but it doesn't work.

**views.py**

```
if(request.GET.get('delete')):  #if the button is clicked
    delete_article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=id)

    if request.POST:
        form = DeleteNewForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid(): 
            delete_article.delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

**template.html**

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action="." method="post" class="form"  autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">TITRE
      {{ form.title.errors }}
      {{ form.title }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">CONTENU
      {{ form.media }}
      {{ form.contenu.errors }}
      {{ form.contenu }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.image.errors }}
      {{ form.image }}
   </div>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Edit Article"/>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Delete Article" name="delete">
</form>
```

**Here is what happen when I submit the form** : I am not redirected on the index as it should redirect me and the article has not been deleted.

Is there a problem which don't let me delete my article in these lines?

Comment: It looks like your view function isn't going to work because you have an if statement guarding for only a get request when you are then looking for POST parameters. **EDIT** I would also recommend using the Class Based Views for simplicity and sanity - see the documentation for edit based generic CBVs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Comment: were you trying to delete in framework or front-end ?

Comment: are you sure your form validates?

Comment: @Pynchia from front-end I'm don't think the form validates

Comment: @theWanderer4865 Yes, I tried with post, it is still not working and don't worry I'm using the Class Based Views, it's just that this code share the same function as another one, that's why I use the first if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you're doing in your views or in your template. But if I want to delete something, I just define a separate view for that.

```
# views.py

from django.views.generic.base import View

class DeleteView(View):
    def post(self, request *args, **kwargs):
        article = get_object_or_404(id=request.POST['article_id'])
        # perform some validation, 
        # like can this user delete this article or not, etc.
        # if validation is successful, delete the article
        article.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Your template should be like this:

```
<form action="/url/to/delete/view/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ article.id }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Comment: On the model.py, I don't really understand the first line, what should I put on the - DeleteView(**?**) -. the name of my View or the path to the view?

Comment: @Sia It's not `models.py` file, it's your `views.py` actually. And `DeleteView` is a [class based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/). In one of your comments above you've said you're using class based views, so I though you'd know. Anyways, I've updated the code with more info.

Comment: Oh thanks! But I got an error, **__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)** How can I resolve that? (I also added a ',' between `request` and `*args`) Here is my **urls.py** `url(r'^delete/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'DeleteView', name='DeleteView'),`

Comment: @Sia Since, it's a class based view, it's url should look like this: `url(r'^delete/(?P<id>\d+)/$', DeleteView.as_view())`. Also, don't forget to put `from myapp.views import DeleteView` in your urls.py. And please, do read the docs on class based views.

Comment: Thank you I'll see the documentation you mentionned, I missunderstood what was class based views, I'll check that right now!